# How to create contacts with Live REST API?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, live

I've a really problem on Live REST API with Javascript.

Indeed, I'm trying to get contacts from a user id (after logged in) and to insert new ones.
But I've a "header" issue.

Here is my connexion function :

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    $("#ifConnect").hide();

    WL.login({
        scope: "wl.signin, wl.basic, wl.emails, wl.contacts_create"
    }).then(
        function (response) {
            loadContacts(); //which load properly my contacts
        }
    );
});
```

And here is my create contact lines :

```
var contact = { 
    first_name: "First", 
    last_name: "Last"
};

WL.api({
    path: "me/contacts", 
    method: "POST",
    body: contact
}).then(
    function (response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    },
    function (response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    }
);
```

Unfortunately, the second function is called, and gimme a header alert : 
`{"error":{"code":"request_body_invalid_media_type","message":"The request doesn't include a Content-Type header."}}`

Is someone can help me ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: what does chrome dev console/firebug say? does it show its not sending `Content-type` header?

Answer (score 0):

error description is quite informative. Try to set Content-Type to *application/json* or 
put the body like in this example:

```
 function (response) {
         WL.api({
            path: "me/contacts",
            method: "POST",
            body: {
                "first_name": "First",
                "last_name": "Last"
            }
```

Comment: With PUT method, Live return `HTTP method 'PUT' isn't allowed for this resource.`
And how to set a content type with this function ?

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. You don't need to set content-type because live api do it for you. Try to use hardcoded body (see updated answer). If it won't help try to see what exactly is sent to server. Use fiddler or firebug, like shiplu.mokadd.im  suggested